# Convert an array filled with objects

Tags: php

I have an array that give objects back like this:

```
array (size=61)
  0 => 
    object(Xxx\Car)[602]
      private 'id' => int 53
      private 'name' => string 'Volkswagen' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(Xxx\Car)[594]
      private 'id' => int 43
      private 'name' => string 'Toyota' (length=6)
  2 => 
    object(Xxx\Car)[595]
      private 'id' => int 32
      private 'name' => string 'BMW' (length=3)
```

How can I convert the array to so that the id become the key and the value the description, like this:

```
array (size=61)
  53 => 'Volkswagen'
  43 => 'Toyota'
  32 => 'BMW'
```

I've tried

```
$cars = array();    
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $cars[$value['id']] = $value['name'];
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: try storing the key and val in an intermediate variable first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are treating your objects as if they were arrays.

`$array['key']` is the notation for accessing an element in an array, but `$object->key` is the one for an object.

Try this :

```
$cars = array();    
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $cars[$value->id] = $value->name;
}
```

EDIT : If that doesn't work (due to the `private` nature of the elements), you might have to declare functions like `getID()` and `getName()` in your object class file, and use them as such :

```
$cars = array();    
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    $cars[$value->getID()] = $value->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$arr = get_object_vars($obj);` function. It converts an object to an array.